# Does MySQL update priority affect query ordering on same connection?

Tags: mysql

I understand the point of update priorities is to change the ordering of queries on different connections, but will lowering the priority of MySQL updates with LOW_PRIORITY or --low-priority-updates ever cause the same MySQL connection to execute queries out of order?

Answer (score 1):

No. Queries issued through the same connection are always executed sequentially and synchronously.

Comment: Do you have any source to supplement this answer?